# Communicate between two systems using only MAC address

Tags: c, networking, network-programming, networkstream

I want to know how to communicate between two systems using only MAC address using **C program** (without using IP address). I think this is raw ethernet communication. My requirement is to send data from client to server only by using the MAC address. May be this can be done by creating our own raw ethernet frame.

Please help me regarding this. If anybody has written code in C, please share.

This link may help you, http://aschauf.landshut.org/fh/linux/udp_vs_raw/ch01s03.html

Comment: What OS? Can you establish a link local IP address?

Comment: You also have to make sure that the client and server are on the same subnet (ie. no router in between the two). If they are on the same hub you should be ok.

Comment: I am using Linux syetm (Ubuntu). Yes I can communicate between the two syetems using IP address and both are in same network. At least I should be able to communicate within the system, I mean by running client program in one terminal and server program in another terminal, I should receive the data in server terminal. This link may help you, http://aschauf.landshut.org/fh/linux/udp_vs_raw/ch01s03.html

Answer (score 3):

The libpcap library allows you to assemble raw Ethernet packets and send them directly to an adapter: the hardest part being the discovery of the correct adapter. This is designed for C/C++ usage on most platforms (Win PCAP etc.).

Be sure this is what you want though: I have seen several projects where raw Ethernet packet interfaces have been used, only for more and more protocol to be put in place for re-transmission and windowing etc. until you end up with your own version of TCP/IP (only one that hasn't been tested by millions of people using Windows/Linux or whatever your platform is). Most Ethernet chips have functions to accelerate TCP/IP stacks these days too: so you will be missing out on that too.

Comment: And if all else fails and you really do need this, you could use it only to exchange a more useful identifier (IP address or host name).

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/netfxnetcom/thread/73c94eb5-df9b-42df-9a4e-e321e6ca344d) are examples for C#, maybe you can leverage this. The right code depends on OS and even from the used chips when programming for microcontrollers.