# how to set a DNS name to avoid changing IP

Tags: dns, ip

I have a phone app (Xamarin forms) that acts as a server and a myriad o nodemcu devices (microPython) that can act as a remote sensors and post data to the server via TCP (I'm not using mqtt).

My devices can connect to my home WiFi or, if I'm abroad and the SSID is not present, they look for the adhoc WiFi created from the phone itself.

My problem is that the IP of the server changes. I can set static IP for my home network but it definitely changes if I'm connected to my home WiFi or to the adhoc WiFi created from the phone.

Is there a way to provide a DNS name to my sever (phone) and allow the clients to find it in the network by it's name? 
If that's impossible.. is there a way to broadcast the server IP using TCP? I'd hate to create another socket using UDP just for that :(

Comment: Maybe you can send raw Ethernet packet to the phone server, using MAC address, and get the correct IP address (in response)? Here is a SO thread about the how-to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6686256/communicate-between-two-systems-using-only-mac-address

Comment: this would mean that I need to change the code (at least the MAC) to run it from another tablet. Doesn't it ?

Comment: If the tablet acts as server, yes...